# GeoCoordinate or DbGeography for coordinate?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am storing longitude and latitude for each record so that I will be able to do queries based on distance from a certain point.

What is the best data type to use for storing the long/lat?

Some Googling has turned up DbGeography & GeoCoordinate but the documentation isn't really very clear and I can't find any good recent articles.

What data type should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GeoCoordinate is for use with receiving sensor data on things like mobile devices. For database storage you should be using `System.Data.Spatial.DbGeography` if you are on .NET 4.5 or `System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography` if you are using Entity Framework and are on .NET 4.0 or older. The datatype in your database should be [geography](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280766.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I will use the DbGeograpy type